# NHibernate: Custom Criterion to manipulate joins

Tags: .net, nhibernate

I have an odd requirement that my clients have imposed on me.  They have certain queries which they have spent a lot of time optimizing that work as follows:

1. A stored procedure builds up an "id-list" which basically represents the "Where" filter
2. The id-list is joined into your data tables

The id-list would look something like this

IdListTable.Customers_Id

```
1087,
10094,
87,
1077
```

The joining query therefore looks like:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.FirstName, c.LastName
FROM Customers c INNER JOIN IdListTable idList ON (c.Id = idList.Customers_Id);
```

I would like to be able to do something like this in NHibernate

```
IEnumerable<Customer> GetMatching(Specification spec) {
  string idListName = "IdListTable";

  _idListGenerator.BuildIdList(idListName);

  return _session.CreateCriteria<Customer>().
    Add(new JoinIdListCriterion(idListName)
    .Enumerable<Customer>()
}
```

So first of all, is this the correct concept?  Do I want to implement my own ICriterion or is that for something else altogether?

Secondly, how do I actually do this.  I've tried implementing AbstractCriterion and reading the doc-comments and I'm just not sure where I would hook into the query building process.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to add the "id-list" table to your mappings, so you can perform the join just like any other table.

Another option is to perform the join on the WHERE clause, so you'll get something like:

```
SELECT c.Id, c.FirstName, c.LastName
FROM Customers c WHERE c.Id IN (SELECT Customers_Id FROM IdListTable);
```

You can make it work using a SqlCriteria:

```
return _session.CreateCriteria<Customer>("c")
  .Add(Expression.Sql("c.Id IN (SELECT Customers_Id FROM IdListTable)", new object[0], new IType[0]))
  .Enumerable<Customer>();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to map the id-list because its not an entity.  an IN query is one way of doing it, sure but I would really like to get it to work as a Join.  It would seem the ICriterion exposes the hooks for this, but I'm unsure how.

Comment: Hey Fabio, how would this work with caching, transactions, etc.  It would seem like there is no way that NHibernate can do anything on those fronts and you'd loose much of the benefits of using it to begin with.

Comment: Caching and Transactions should still work fine, I use Expression.Sql a lot in some projects and never had any problem with it. As for joining, as long as you're using the criteria API, you must either map all your tables (that's why you probably should map IdListTable, even if it's not an entity, it's still an important part of your model), or try to "hijack" your query using the IN clause or some user-defined functions. Another option is to write this specific query using pure SQL (by using _session.CreateSQLQuery()).